# python replace list values using a tuple

Tags: python, list

If I have a list:

```
my_list = [3,2,2,3,4,1,3,4]
```

and a tuple

```
my_tuple = (3,5)
```

What's the best way of replacing elements in `my_list` using the tuple:

```
result = [5,2,2,5,4,1,5,4]
```

e.g.

```
for item in my_list:
    if(item == my_tuple[0]):
        item = my_tuple[1]
```

More generally, I would have a list of lists, and a list of tuples, and I would like to apply each of the tuples to each of the lists within the list of lists.

Comment: The approach in your example is basically sound, except that the assignment won't work because you're working on a copy of the value in the list. You need to enumerate the list and replace the value at the correct index if your criterion is met. (List comprehensions are better for the simple case, but may get ugly for the list of lists and list of tuples).

Comment: I still get confused as to when python makes copies and uses references ...

Comment: Don't be confused, it's really very simple: Python *always uses references.*

Comment: Except that `item` in the above is a copy!

Comment: `item` will actually be a reference to the elements in `my_list`, but since `my_list` contains only immutable types it won't really matter.  If `my_list` was a list of lists you could do something like `item[:] = [1, 2]` and modify the contents of `my_list`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The more natural data structure for `my_tuple` is a dictionary.  Consider something like this and use the `.get()` method:

```
>>> my_lists = [[3,2,2,3,4,1,3,4], [1,2,3,4,5,6]]
>>> my_tuple_list = [(3,5), (6, 7)]
>>> my_dict = dict(my_tuple_list)
>>> my_dict
{3: 5, 6: 7}
>>> my_lists = [[my_dict.get(x,x) for x in somelist] for somelist in my_lists]
>>> my_lists
[[5, 2, 2, 5, 4, 1, 5, 4], [1, 2, 5, 4, 5, 7]]
```

Comment: `get(x, x)` ... that's beautiful!

Comment: Perfect! Hadn't thought of using a dictionary, makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 3):

Per @Wooble's comment, your code will work if you enumerate.

```
list_of_lists = [[3,2,2,3,4,1,3,4], [1,3,5,3,4,6,3]]
list_of_tuples = [(3,5), (1,9)]

def tup_replace(mylist, mytuple):
    for i, item in enumerate(mylist):
        if item == mytuple[0]:
            mylist[i] = mytuple[1]
    return mylist
```

then you can just nest that some more to work on a list of list and list of tuples.

```
for mylist in list_of_lists:
    for mytuple in list_of_tuples:
        mylist = tup_replace(mylist, mytuple)
    print mylist
```

That said, the dictionary approach is probably better.

Comment: +1, because I think it makes more sense for there to be a variety of answers with different approaches (even if some are less efficient) than a bunch of similar answers which evolve into each other.  IMHO each question usually should have at least two answers: one, explaining how to fix the apparent problem in the OP's code, and two, explaining how the OP should really have solved the problem in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to replace every `3` in your list with `5`, this will do:

```
[x == my_tuple[0] and my_tuple[1] or x for x in my_list]
```

If you want to do this, with more than one "translational" tuple, then I really suggest to use a dictionary instead:

```
trans = {3: 5, 4: 6}
[trans.get(x,x) for x in my_list]
```

And in the more general case where you have more than one list:

```
ll = [[3, 2, 3, 4], [5, 4, 3, 4]]
trans = {3: 5, 4: 6}
for i in range(len(ll)):
    ll[i] = [trans.get(x,x) for x in ll[i]]
```

Supposing that you want to replace every old list in `ll` with the new one.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure: The OP asked how to do this and more generally with multiple lists and translate tuples. I've just updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using if item == my_tuple[0], ... in a general case sounds like you are making a switch statement that you want to apply to each item in your list. Use a dictionary instead if you can. ([Why isn't there a switch or case statement in python?](http://docs.python.org/faq/design.html#why-isn-t-there-a-switch-or-case-statement-in-python))

Convert your list of tuples to a lookup dictionary (python's switch statement):

```
replacements = dict(my_tuples) #thanks to @julio
```

Then for a single list, reproduce the list with a comprehension, but replace each value with the new value from replacements if it exists:

```
replaced_list = [replacements.get(original,original) for original in my_list]
```

I guess there is a more efficient way to do it, but that's for a single list with a list of tuples. You say you also need to do it for a list of lists? Just nest that?

Could you explain more about where you are getting this data and why you need to do it?

Comment: More pythonic: `replacements = dict(my_tuples)`

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks and I will update the answer. More importantly, I missed the case of not having all items in the replacements.